# Cannot set speed of USB adapter

Tags: networking, network-adapter, speed, adapter, gigabit-ethernet

SO, I have a USB 3 to Gigabit Ethernet adapter, When I try to change speed and duplex of this interface

```
ethtool -s eth1 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on
```

I get:

> Cannot get current device settings: Operation not supported   not
>   setting speed   not setting duplex   not setting autoneg

Is there a way to set speed of network adapter?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... Are you `root` or running the command with `sudo`? It is not clear in the question. Also see [ethtool Fails to Force Duplex Mode](https://support.cumulusnetworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/201787516-ethtool-Fails-to-Force-Duplex-Mode). The article says *"The native Linux ethtool is not capable of configuring front panel ports."*

Comment: I think this link may be helpful to you. https://www.shellhacks.com/change-speed-duplex-ethernet-card-linux/   This link may be helpful too. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-change-the-speed-and-duplex-settings-of-an-ethernet-card/

Comment: @jww I ran the command with sudo.